# SmartTV - not responding pages

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I try to develop an application for smartTV. I spend my two days really and didnt reach anyting.

I have a strange problem.

if you click below link you will see page page for smartTV 
http://portal.sinemalar.com/tv/vestel/v1/detail/48029/

And you can use up and down arrow keys if you want to see more details about movie.

```
 case KEYS.UP:
            var $kayan = document.getElementById('ozet_p');
            if (!$kayan.style.top)
                $kayan.style.top = "0px";
            var $top = $kayan.style.top;
            $top = $top.substr(0,$top.length-2);
            $height = $kayan.offsetHeight;
            if (0<parseInt($top) + 120)
                $top = 0;
            else
                $top = parseInt($top) + 120;
            $kayan.style.top = $top+'px';               
            break;
      case KEYS.DOWN:
            $kayan = document.getElementById('ozet_p');
            if (!$kayan.style.top)
                $kayan.style.top = "0px";
            $top = $kayan.style.top;
            $top = $top.substr(0,$top.length-2);
            $height = $kayan.offsetHeight;
            $max = 225-$height;
            if ($max<0)
            {
                if ($max>parseInt($top) - 120)
                    $top = $max;
                else
                    $top = parseInt($top) - 120;

                $kayan.style.top = $top+'px'; 
            }

            break;
```

This part is also work on my smartTV issueless

i have one more page which shows comment of movies

http://portal.sinemalar.com/tv/vestel/v1/comment/48029/1/1/1/1/

you can also use up and down keys if you want to see more comment.
and this is its code

```
 case KEYS.UP:
            if ($page>1)
            {
                $page--;            
                window.location.href = baseUrl+'comment/'+$movieId+'/'+$vPage+'/'+$yPage+'/'+$slot+'/'+$page+'/';
            }            
            break;
        case KEYS.DOWN:
            $page++;
            window.location.href = baseUrl+'comment/'+$movieId+'/'+$vPage+'/'+$yPage+'/'+$slot+'/'+$page+'/';
            break;
```

Problem is that this part works on pc and not work on the smartTV.

What might be the problem? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should package your app for the TV, and while leaving your SDK IDE open, run the application on TV, it should show debug information in the same place while developing on PC. Maybe it will show some relevant information.

Samsung SmartTV still is very unstable and buggy platform to develop for. Lots of features does not work in SDK, so you need to test it on device to be sure.

Comment: +1 for "unstable and buggy", i've spent 2 days on it and still cannot start apps on the TV (apps that work in the emulator though), seems like crap to me.